# How to replace semicolons?

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-server-2005

I have an SQL `SELECT` query that's grabbing some data from my database. I need to replace a certain word that contains a semicolon in my `SELECT` query. Exactly this:

```
REPLACE(Table.Field,'&quot;','') AS Field1
```

The error I'm getting reads

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '"'.

So I think the semicolon is terminating the query. How can I escape that semicolon?

I tried backslashes and using double quotes.

Some sample data and expected output, as requested

---

### Sample data

```
Field
&quot;Hello&quot;
&quot;Goodbye&quot;
```

---

### Expected output

```
Field1
Hello
Goodbye
```

---

### Full Query

```
SELECT REPLACE(Table.Name,';','') AS Name,
    SUM(Table.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
    SUM(Table.Price*Table.Quantity) AS Price 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: @wewesthemenace Tried that. I am trying to replace that whole string of text though... not just the semicolon

Comment: I see. Can you provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: It's working fine in mine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5581/0

Comment: My query is exactly as you see here. Might have something to do with the version? I'm on 2005

Comment: Working fine with me on 2012 as well

Comment: Just tried it with sql-server 2005. Still working fine. Can you post your whole query?

Comment: @wewesthemenace There it is

Comment: Can you comment out this line and run your query? you might be having a quote somewhere in the editor that you are not paying attention to.

Comment: @Ala if I remove the semicolon, it runs. I really think the semicolon is terminating the query

Comment: Can you create an sql fiddle for the sample data? and you whole query. Still can't replicate this.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this error on db layer? Can you run your query in SSMS and see if you get the error? I checked it with 2005+ and it's working.

Comment: If you believe it's happening in your db layer and the semicolon is the problem, try quotation(') before the semicolon(;). ' is for escaping ' but you can give it a go.

Comment: Can you split your data to test the query. I want to know that this error occur with every row or some specific row.

Can you also provide whole sql scrip include table schema, data inside, stored proc, etc..

Comment: Are you saying that when you run `SELECT REPLACE(Table.Field,'&quot;','') FROM Table` from SSMS you get an error message, but when you run `SELECT REPLACE(Table.Field,'&quot','') FROM Table` it works fine? It is very hard to believe that.

Comment: Do you get this error when calling this sql in your application or when running it from SSMS? I think, it may be coming from your application where you may not have escaped quotes correctly. Can you post your application code where is query is used?

Comment: I think we need a picture of your error message ;).

Comment: First - as others have mentioned the above code should be working fine in SSMS.    Are you using ADO.NET to execute this query from your application?   I wonder if the anti-bobby-drop-tables code in ADO is terminating your SQL.  SQL Injection attempts to use ;   Use SQL Profiler and enable the Pre statement (default is off - only Completed goes through).  Capture the statement that is sent to SS.   Enable SP:StmtStarting and SQL:StmtStarting.

Comment: Is your actual data in each field more like this: &quot;Hello&quot;,&quot;World&quot;   In other words, do you have a quote enclosed comma delimited list in each field?

Comment: I believe that it's something with the application you're using that's converting the **&quot;** to a single quote in the data. As a workaround, would you be able to create a **View** to **Replace** the **&quot;** as you did in your FULL Query? **OR** maybe REPLACE(Table.Field, CHAR(38) + 'quot;', '')  to avoid the HTML tag?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Precisely. Except I'm not using SSMS

Comment: @ughai Most likely is my application and I can't use another. This was provided by the software company.

Comment: @Ramoth No, I do not.

Comment: @HannoverFist Thank you for not suggesting that I was either lying, confused or doing something wrong. I tried your second solution. I got the message unclosed quotation mark after quot. This furthered my theory that the semicolon was terminating the query. Then I looked up the ASCII number for semicolon and did the reverse '&quot' + CHAR(59) which worked. Please post an answer

Comment: @henryaaron, the fact that you are not using SSMS is the most important bit of information that you didn't share with us for 15 days. Whatever application you are using is messing with the text of SQL query. You can choose to avoid this particular problem by making sure that the text of your SQL query doesn't have any parts that may have special meaning in HTML as in the suggested workaround or you can choose to solve it by investigating what, why and how alters the text of your SQL query and configure/adjust/fix your unnamed application that does it.

Comment: So is your issue resolved by using **CHAR**? I think you are incorrect about the semi-colon ending the query because the application that you are using is interpreting the **&quot;** as a double quote. I think it's because there is now (after the HTML is interpreted) a single double quote that you get the **Unclosed Quote** error. Try SELECT GETDATE() "

Answer (score 12):

The `;` symbol doesn't terminate the query and it should not be escaped, if it is part of the string literal (the text enclosed in single quotes `'`).

Here is a complete example that demonstrates that it works fine in SSMS:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Name varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Name) VALUES('Field');
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Name) VALUES('&quot;Hello&quot;');
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Name) VALUES('&quot;Goodbye&quot;');

SELECT
    Name
    ,REPLACE(Name,'&quot;','') AS ReplacedName
FROM #TempTable;

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

This is the result set:

```
Name                   ReplacedName
----                   ------------
Field                  Field
&quot;Hello&quot;      Hello
&quot;Goodbye&quot;    Goodbye
```

You didn't provide all details of how you construct and execute your query, so I have a guess. It looks like you are:

- building the text of the query dynamically
- use some web-based tools/languages/technologies for that
- web-based text processing tool/language that you use parses the text of your SQL query as if it was HTML and interferes with the result. For one thing, it changes `&quot;` to the `"` symbol.
- during all this processing you end up with unmatched `'` symbol in the text of your SQL. It could come from the user input that you concatenate to your query of from a value stored in your database.
- it has nothing to do with the `;` symbol. Your error message clearly states that the matching quotation mark (which is `'`) is missing after the `"` symbol.

To understand what is going on you should print out the text of the actual SQL query that is sent to the server. Once you have it, it should become obvious what went wrong. I don't think that the Full Query that you put in the question is the real query that you are trying to run. It has syntax error. So, get the real thing first.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me

```
declare @a as nvarchar(50) = '&quot;Hello&quot;'
select REPLACE(@a,'&quot;','') AS Field1

declare @b as nvarchar(50) = '&quot;Goodbye&quot;'
select REPLACE(@b,'&quot;','') AS Field1
```

Error message says unclosed quotation mark ?

Do you have single quotes in few of your fields ?
In that case you can replace them first as below

```
REPLACE(Table.Field,'''','') AS Field1
```

Let me know you need more help with this.

Answer (score 2):

- [Source](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_13.html)

> ```
> &quot;  
>     the double quote sign "
> ```

I think there is no where that this parameter is known as a special phrase that refers to `"` and cause you error message.

---

In SQL Server there is just a function like **`QUOTENAME ( 'character_string' [ , 'quote_character' ] )`** that used like this: -Just for `'` or `"` or `[]`-

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('Sample', '"') --> result is `"Sample"`
SELECT QUOTENAME('Sam"ple', '"') --> result is `"Sam""ple"`
```

---

In SQL Server identifiers can be delimited by `"`, When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON` -for following the ISO rules-. When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `OFF`, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. *Literals can be delimited by either single or double quotation marks.*

I suggest you using `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` that make sure, that you've not identifier between `"` in your query.

> *Note:*
>   When a table is created, the `QUOTED IDENTIFIER` option is always stored as ON in the table's metadata even if the option is set to OFF when the table is created.

---

If you are using a SQL string I suggest this syntax:

```
REPLACE(Table.Field, CHAR(34), '') As Field1
```

or

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(Table.Field, ';', '.'), '&quot.', '') As Field1
```